# Which is idiomatic: "kite is flying" or "kite is floating"?

Tags: word-choice, verbs, nouns, collocation

Is it idiomatic to say "A kite is floating in the sky"?

Most of the time I see "A kite is flying in the sky".

Comment: A "kite floating in the sky" would suggest that there was no one controlling it, like a helium balloon that is released into the sky.

Answer (score 1):

You **fly a kite**. I have never heard anyone floating a kite.

Metaphorically, I suppose, you could imagine as if a **kite were floating on the waves of air**, like a boat. But it's still a bit unusual.